# Which framework should I use in my hybrid app?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to build a hybrid app can run on all devices. I use Phonegap to interact with the device and Jquery mobile for the UI, but I feel the Jquery mobile has performance issues.

What other choices are there to build a hybrid app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend reading co-creator of Phonegap and XUI, Brock Whitten's blog post dealing with the performance of Phonegap apps @ http://sintaxi.com/you-half-assed-it

It's a very good read and the tl;dr of it to answer your question he gives the examples [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com/) or [XUI](http://xuijs.com/) and generally recommends staying away from anything jQuery-based.

Comment: tks actually I used it,it's simply to use it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use sencha-touch 2 to develop  phone gap applications. Sencha touch has an impressive performance on mobile devices.
i think this will be helpful to u http://floatlearning.com/2011/03/developing-better-phonegap-apps/.
You could also use xui or zepto.Zepto has similar syntax with jquery,but is not that heavy.